# OneSignal iOS Settings keeps disappearing

Tags: ios, react-native, onesignal

I'm currently working on implementing push notification for my app using React Native and OneSignal. I've managed to set the settings for Android and iOS, but I noticed the iOS side keeps disappearing from time to time and appearing again. Same thing with the dashboard, the iOS logo sometimes appear and disappear.

When trying to send notification while only targeting my iOS device, sometimes the system would show Total Number of Recipient to be 0 as well. The device itself only received the notifications from time to time while the android side always received them.

Anyone ever have this issue as well? And did you managed to solve it?

EDIT:

I cannot seem to find a way to fix this so I decided to do a workaround instead by creating another project inside OneSignal and disable the old one. The push notification is working fine now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OneSignal fixed this issue today with the dashboard not saving/persisting data. You should be able to save your settings now. Best to contact OneSignal directly with issues like this.